# Open Activity from listView Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

This is my first app. I have a fragment that is populated by a list view, that gets the data from a webservice. I want to be able to click on a list view item and open a new activity. Although it will be the same activity for each item, I am going to pass a different variable. I've seen a lot of other post about this. None of them work for me. Please help thanks.

```
public class TicketFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView tv;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public TicketFragment(){}
    private String TAG ="Vik";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ticket, container, false);
        tv =(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
        task.execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            location();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
           // Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
           // Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading locations.....");
        }

    }     

    public void location() {
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://example.com/getlocations";
        String METHOD_NAME = "getlocations";
        String NAMESPACE = "http://example.com/";
        String URL = "http://localhost/Example/Service.asmx";   

        try { 
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            //Request.addProperty("get locations", "3");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

            HttpTransportSE transport= new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

            SoapObject response = (SoapObject)soapEnvelope.getResponse();

            System.out.println(response);
            int intPropertyCount = response.getPropertyCount();
            String[] locations= new String[intPropertyCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < intPropertyCount; i++) {               
                locations[i] = response.getPropertyAsString(i).toString();
            }

            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, locations);

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This code will always run on the UI thread, therefore is safe to modify UI elements.
                    tv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: What i have is working. I don't know how to make the List View Clickable and open a new activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a click listener to your list view:

```
tv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DestinationActivity.class);
        // add data to the intent...
        startActivity(intent);
}
```